# What is the advantage of increasing minimum password length? (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for my user auth system, and I'm wondering if it makes any difference to increase the minimum password length to 10 characters. Does that make the passwords a lot harder to crack? Is there an equally large performance hit for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make the password harder to crack.

This is because of the combinatorial effect. The longer the password the more combinations to try to successfully find the password.

There will not be much of a performance hit in your use case. The only downside, if there is one; is that users have to choose a longer password.